# Transferring Facebook data into Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase-realtime-database

On my login page, I have the option to register using Facebook. When the user clicks on my custom FB button this code runs

```
func handleCustomFBLogin() {
    FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, err) in
        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {

            print("user is logged in")

        }else{
            print("user is not logged in")
        }

        }

    }
```

What i'm trying to achieve is that when the user clicks the Facebook button and they already have logged in from before, they would be automatically logged in to their user account on Firebase. I was thinking of making a function that would send a graphRequest and get their email that is on their Facebook account since that is what would populate their user account fields.

But if the user pressed the FB button and they are logging in for the first time, I want to be able to create a user account on Firebase for them.

Answer (score 0):

Sure...Firebase got you covered.

Enable Facebook login in the Firebase console.

When logging in with Facebook they return a token back to you.

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString) //this goes in your function you created
```

And then you just authenticate using Firebase as you would normally do:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in

if let error = error {
  // ...
  return
}
```

You can read more about how to do this following a [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login) from Firebase where this example is taken from.

Edit:

When firebase have created an account for the user you can use callback to get the uid for the user and create an entry to your firebase database. or you can get the currently logged in user like this:

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
// The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project.
// Do NOT use this value to authenticate with your backend server,
// if you have one. Use getTokenWithCompletion:completion: instead.
let email = user?.email
let uid = user?.uid
let photoURL = user?.photoURL
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I'm trying to not just authenticate them, i'm trying to add them to my Firebase database under my user node that I store all of my users under. So essentially, I just want to pull the users Facebook information and create a Firebase user from it @Joakim

Comment: I understand. See my updated answer. Once you have the uid for the user you can add the to your firebase database user node.  This works if you use the users unique id for the node id?